# SOQL/SQL: Result of left outer join query is not correct

Tags: sql, join, salesforce, soql

I am quite stuck regarding a query. I have three objects in Salesforce: Contact, CampaignMember, Campaign.
Now, I want to get all the contacts which are in campaign 'A' but NOT in campaign 'B'.
My code belwo doesn't work:

`SELECT Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName, Contact.ID FROM CampaignMember WHERE Campaign.Name= 'A' AND Campaign.Name != 'B'`

Salesforce simply ignores the part:

```
 AND Campaign.Name != 'B'
```

Nevertheless I get all the contacts which are in 'A'. Not the difference between A&B, which I wanted.

If I switch to `!= B`only, it returns zero contacts, which is not correct.

I suppose it is because the link between campaign and contact is made through the campaignmember object and I am trying to do a left outer join on the campaign where I want the contacts of campaign 'A' which are not in 'B'.

Is there a way to get this done? I would appreciate any help.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your query doesn't have a table `Contact` nor `Campaign`, so your query results in an error. Please show your *full* query

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation.  Assuming no duplicates:

```
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.ID
FROM CampaignMember c
WHERE c.Name IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND MAX(c.Name) = 'A';
```

If you do have duplicates, you can use:

```
HAVING MIN(c.Name) = MAX(c.Name) AND MAX(c.Name) = 'A'
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for your answer. It looks very promising but unfortunately I get the following error message:

MALFORMED_QUERY: unexpected token: 'HAVING'

Furthermore I don't get this bit:

    FROM CampaignMember c      as c is the object contact.

I'd be very happy if you have any idea how to troubleshoot this issue. Thank, in advance!

Comment: @Lekü . . . There is no `FROM CampaignMember c as c` in this query.  There is also no obvious syntax error, and the syntax works:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3b986d3fd96786fe3421570e1fc6563f.  You can try it in different engines.

Comment: @Gordan Linoff: I see, thank you for clarifying and the attached link. However, I can't run it in workbench.developerforce.com under SOQL Query. Any idea, how I can run it there without getting the error above?

Comment: @Lekü . . . SOQL supports `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.  It is really unclear to me what the problem could be.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff . . . Sorry, SOQL Query in Workbench flagged the HAVING statement but the problem is: unexpected token: '*'   I read it up and as I understand SOQL doesn't know the *. Anyways, thank you for your input which was really useful for a newbie like me.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is related to general SQL not SOQL (also the Comment under your question is wrong as these are not tables but fields on Lookup fields - again SOQL specific thing).

Your query does exactly what you asked it to do - in the where clause:

`Campaign.Name= 'A' AND Campaign.Name != 'B'`

When `Campaign.Name = 'A'` it can never be equal to `'B'` at the same time (because it is `'A'`).

There is separate CampaignMember record for every Contact & Campaign combination.

What you could try to do is something like:

```
SELECT Id FROM CampaignMember
WHERE Campaign.Name = 'A' 
  AND ContactId NOT IN (
   SELECT ContactId FROM CampaignMember
     WHERE Campaign.Name = 'B'
  )
```

However this will not work - as you can't have subquery on the same object as the main query in SOQL.

In the end the only solution is to query both Campaigns (either in 1 or 2 queries) & do the diff in Apex - you can do it in 1 for cycle - O(n).

Unfortunately SOQL itself can't do what you are trying to achieve.